# How to delete/erase/remove blank line from host file?

Tags: c#, host

I wanna remove blank line from host file specifically.

Suppose, the host file has 25 lines where 4 lines totally blank and we assumed that those 4 blank lines are last 4 line. So I want after 21 lines, all blank lines will be removed and then the host file will saved.

I have no idea & no code to do that..Please help me about that If u can.

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces: 1. Read the file, 2. remove empty lines, 3. write the file. Research each of these pieces individually.

Comment: Can u give me the code..

Answer (score 2):

```
string path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)));
```

Old .Net Version:

```
string path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this:

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using(var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
{
    string line;

    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         if(line != "removeme")
             sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

File.Delete("file.txt");
File.Move(tempFile, "file.txt");
```